# The character - is not applied c++

Tags: c++, char

Hi i have some problem with the caracter '-', when I change this character this is not applied... Why?

```
 string parola;
 getline(cin, parola);
 char array[10];

for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    array[i]=parola[i];
}

cout<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(array[i]=='*')
        array[i]='-';
    if(array[i]=='-')
        array[i]='*';

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The second `if` changes it back. Instead use `else if`:

```
if(array[i]=='*') {
    array[i]='-';
} else if(array[i]=='-'){
    array[i]='*';
}
```

Comment: what is the best among cin >> or getline ( cin , string ) ? @Bathsheba

Comment: I prefer cin>> but either will do here.